# Deleting Azure App Service Plan

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans

I am trying to delete app service plan from azure portal and understand the fact that it cant be deleted if an app sits in the service plan. Found an interesting thing here, even though there is no app or slots available in service plan it is not allowing me to delete app service plan. Following screen, any help or insights is appreciated-

[image]

[image]

Comment: the app you last deleted may not be completely deleted as it is an asynchronous process.

Comment: Either try removing the Resource Group altogether (if possible) or go to https://resources.azure.com and try to invoke the DELETE action from there (it may list one or more apps that you no longer see in the Portal).

Comment: @evilSnobu suggestion is the best bet, check also the locks, but it would give you a different error if it was a lock.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue, this is how I deal with it.
The fact you see the number of apps/slots with the values 0/0, means you app has been well deleted. But your browser still keep in memory the old values, reason why it display a message saying one app is still in the Service Plan.

If you simply hit F5, the value will be updated and you'll be able to remove the App Service Plans.

Comment: This did not work for me. I had to wait a few minutes until the delete request was accepted. Maybe for you this coincidentally happened at the same time that you refreshed the page?